# What does Bmesh mean as opposed to mesh in animation nodes mean?

Tags: mesh, animation-nodes, bmesh

I tried to find the answer on Google and it did not give any answers for me. I also tried on this forum and I did not get any answers here either. So what is the difference between Bmesh and mesh especially with relevance to Animation nodes, but I assume it has relevance to whole of Blender?

Comment: Mesh (blue socket) is Animation nodes native representation, which is optimized for better performance. It is only available inside AN node tree. BMesh is blender mesh type, which supports many operators like smooth, triangulate etc. Manipulation of data is faster when using AN mesh than bmesh due to python overhead.

Comment: Hello @HariSreedhar, you could post this as an answer :)